# Solving an integral over a function

Tags: integration

How can I solve the following integral? I know that replacing $d\mu_{ni}(c)$ with $\mu^{\prime}_{ni}(c)dc$ should help, but I still can't figure out how to obtain the anti-derivative.

$$P_n=\sum^N_{i=1}\int_0^{\overline{c}_{ni}(\eta)}\left(1-\left(\frac{c}{\overline{c}_{ni}(\eta)}\right)^{\lambda(\sigma-1)}\right)c^{1-\sigma}d\mu_{ni}(c),$$

where $\mu_{ni}=\Phi_{ni}c^\theta$.

This is the solution, but I want to be able to reproduce the calculation steps.

$$P_n=\kappa_0 \sum^N_{i=1} \Phi_{ni} \left[ \overline{c}_{ni}(\eta) \right]^{\theta-(\sigma-1)},$$

where $\kappa_0=\frac{\theta}{\theta-(\sigma-1)}-\frac{\theta}{\theta+(\sigma-1)(\lambda-1)}$.

Comment: Some context? Where did this integral come from?

Comment: You should probably at least try to simplify the question down to its central point. Much of the first expression is repeated verbatim in the second, with the only substantive difference being that the integral with respect to $\mu_{ni}(c)$ has been evaluated. So all that really needs to be asked is how to compute that integral; the rest is just a distraction.

Comment: A hint: Consider the substitution $x=c/\overline{c}_{ni}(\eta)$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, hopefully it's concise enough now. The context is economics, we describe a price index as the integral over firm unit costs that are below the maximum unit cost of serving a certain market $i$.